# I am stuck at a Prime Numbers query in python programing

Tags: python

How to write a efficient code to find prime numbers in python?

I have tried simple codes and i need more efficient code.

For example:

```py
num = int(input('Enter the number to check whether it is prime or not: '))

for i in range(2,num):
    if num%i==0:
        print("Not Prime")
        break
        
else:
    print("Prime number")
```

Comment: The simplest efficiency improvement would be to not loop all the way to `num` looking for factors - if you haven't found one by the time you reach the square root of `num`, there can't be any higher ones.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question here is an approach which will determine if a number is prime more efficiently than what you have written, although for large numbers it is still not the best.  In addition, this solution addresses the situation where the user enters 0, 1, or 2.

```
def is_prime(n):
    """
    Integer -> Boolean
    returns True if n is a prime number
    """
    if n == 2 or n == 3:
        return True
    if n < 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False
    if n < 9:
        return True
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return False

    r = int(sqrt(n))
    f = 5
    while f <= r:
        if n % f == 0:
            return False
        if n % (f + 2) == 0:
            return False
        f += 6
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

I find Itprorh66's answer hard to read with the `r` and `f` variables. Jaosnharper's comment about only looping up until the square root is a good idea. Here is some code to make the process faster:

```
import math


def is_prime(number: int) -> bool:
    """
    Summary:
        Check if an integer is a prime number.

    Returns:
        bool: If the input (number) is a prime number or not.
    """

    # One, zero, and negative numbers do not follow the definition of a prime
    # number.
    if number < 2:
        return False

    # Two is an exception with even numbers when considering whether they are
    # prime or not, so it is handled here.
    if number == 2:
        return True

    # Even numbers are always composite (except for two).
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return False

    # Plus one is used to include the final number while in the for-loop.
    square_root_number = math.isqrt(number) + 1

    # There is an increase of two instead of one to iterate over odd divisors
    # only.
    # The for-loop starts at three because numbers lower than three
    # have already been handled.
    for divisor in range(3, square_root_number, 2):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return False

    return True
```